# Enum type with values containing spaces on it

Tags: mysql, enums

Enum values can contain spaces on it?

For example ENUM('item1','the item2','item 3').

It's allowed?

I'm using MySql.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not ? String with space remains string !
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html